# List workspace variables in function

Tags: matlab

In a GUI, I'd like to allow the user to import a value from the workspace. Therefore, I want to show a list of the variables defined in the workspace and let the user select one. Something similar is done, for example, in the `cftool` for the `x`- and `y`- (and `z`-) data.

However, if I use `who` within a function, it does not list the variables in the workspace (Note: The following code creates or overwrites the variable `mytestvar` in your workspace):

```
function listwsvars()
    assignin('base','mytestvar',1);
    vars = whos('global');

    vars
end
```

The result is the same if I omit the `global` argument or use `who` instead of `whos`.

Any idea how I can get a list of the variables in the workspace? And in turn, how can I access them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `whos` will return the variables in the active workspace (in this case, the function *listwsvars*).
With the **global** option, it will return the ones in the global workspace. If you have not defined global variables, this will indeed return empty.

---

A possible solution is to evaluate the `whos` command in the base workspace with `evalin`:

```
function listwsvars()
    assignin('base','mytestvar',1);
    vars = evalin('base','whos');

    vars
end
```

`vars` is a struct array containing information on all the variables available in the base workspace.

Comment: Just a note to readers: this is one of the very few legitimate uses of `evalin`.